# Can I use Spring's MockMvc with Jersey resources?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs, mockmvc

I have successfully integrated Spring and Jersey via Spring Boot' starter POMs, and I have a couple Jersey endpoints. Now I'd like to unit test the resources. I can't seem to get MockMvc working. I get a 404 error when attempting to GET a resource endpoint.

I know there is a Jersey test framework out there, but it appears to launch a server. I'm hoping to avoid "integration" type tests and keep this as simple as possible. Can I do this with MockMvc?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately doesn't seem to be possible as [MockMvc doesn't actually start servlet container](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mvc-test-framework).

You can use

1. `RestTemplate` to fire requests against server started on localhost. Here are examples from Spring Boot repo: [Example 1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jersey) and [Example 2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jersey).
2. [Rest Assured](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured) library

Comment: Example1 and Example 2 are both dead links