# java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404> with jersy-spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mockito, junit4, spring-jersey

controller file[LogController.java file]:

```
@Api(value = "/")
@Path("/")
public class LogController

{

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogController.class);
    private LoggerService loggerService = new LoggerService();

    @GET
    @Path("/getLogServerInfo")
    public String getLogServerInfo(@Context HttpHeaders httpheaders) throws Exception {
        //code
    }
```

unit test code:

```
public class LogControllerTest
{

     private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Mock
    private LoggerServiceLua loggerServiceLua;

    @InjectMocks
    private LogController logController;

    @Before
    public void init(){

        System.out.println("in here 1");
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        System.out.println("in here 1.1");
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(logController)
                .build();
        System.out.println("in here 1 end");
        }


        @Test
        public void testgetLogServerInfo() throws Exception
        {
            /*List<serviceinfo2> serviceinfo = Arrays.asList(
                    new serviceinfo2(1, "Daenerys Targaryen"),
                    new serviceinfo2(2, "John Snow"));*/
                String serviceinfo = new String("{\"_id\":\"log_server\",\"_rev\":\"24-86181b008b62e31b2403852bf70fb8ce\",\"ip_address\":\"192.23.24.12\",\"port\":\"000\"}");
            System.out.println(serviceinfo);
            //serviceinfo2 serviceinfo2 = mock(serviceinfo2.class);
            when(loggerServiceLua.getLogServerInfo()).thenReturn(serviceinfo);
            System.out.println("in here 2");
            mockMvc.perform(get("/getLogServerInfo"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            verify(loggerServiceLua, times(1)).getLogServerInfo();
            verifyNoMoreInteractions(loggerServiceLua);

        }
    }
```

We are using Maven+ jersy framework for restful service Developement but maven:spring,mockito for unit test .

After executing above ,I am getting

### error trace:

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:81)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$10.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:664)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
    at Tests.LogControllerLuaTest.testgetLogServerInfo(LogControllerLuaTest.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Please comment if any other inf is required

Comment: Try to change `@Path("/getLogServerInfo")` to `@Path("getLogServerInfo")` in your controller.

Comment: is`LogControllerLuaTest` the same as `LogControllerTest`? I'm asking because there is a difference between your code and stacktrace

Comment: @Uata LogControllerLuaTest and Logcontroller are different classes

Comment: 1 more question : we have used jersey framework for deveopment and we are using spring for testing rest services ? is it okay to do it this way or it can be problematic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use Spring's MockMvc with Jersey resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644952/can-i-use-springs-mockmvc-with-jersey-resources)